# how to push to root navigator from sub routes when using go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I'm using go_router on flutter, and I have a root routes and a shell route that contains a bottom nav bar on all sub routes. And I want to push a page that is outside of the shell route and I want it to be pushed on the root navigator because it has to be above the bottom nav bar.

I've checked endless documentation of go_router but there is no option to do that.

I have implemented a way to remove all routes and push a page on the root navigator, but when that page is poped it goes to an empty page. but I want it to go to where it was when a page on the shell route.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem. Try adding parentNavigatorKeys and navigatorKeys to your GoRouter.

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _rootNavigator = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'root');
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _shellNavigator =
    GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'shell');

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigator,
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigator,
      path: '/login',
      builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigator,
      builder: (context, state, child) => BottomNav(
        child: child,
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigator,
          path: '/',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const HomeScreen();
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              name: 'nested_view',
              path: 'nested-view',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return const NestedScreen();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
);
```

Then from your code call:

```
context.push('/login')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I was stuck on this for way too long and didn't find any solutions or docs on it.
This should be the accepted answer.